# Does WCF ServiceHost acts as listener or poller?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, msmq

I use WCF with netMsmqBinding. When the `serviceHost` is opened which scenario happens:

1. `serviceHost` registered as listener to MSMQ - on each new arrived message to MSMQ, MSMQ will inform all it's listeners.
2. `serviceHost` will poll MSMQ for new messages -

opening service host

```
using (var serviceHost = new ServiceHost(typeof(Service)))
{                
    serviceHost.Open();

    Console.WriteLine("The service is ready.");
    Console.WriteLine("Press <ENTER> to terminate service.");
    Console.ReadLine();    
}
```

If the first scenario is true, how actually it registered to MSMQ. I didn't found any articles that explain deeply how it happens. I would appreciate for any articles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ServiceHost in this instance is a queue listener.

When a message is received onto the queue, the WCF stack causes your service operation to be called, passing the queue message into your service operation.

> ...MSMQ will inform all it's listeners.

is not correct. If you have multiple listeners on the same queue then only one of them will get the message.

Comment: how WCF registers itself as a listener to MSMQ? Does MSMQ has something like `MSMQ.OnMessageArrived` event and WCF resteres itself to it?

Comment: I don't know. Why are you worried about this? Surely the WCF dev team used whatever mechanism was most appropriate at the time. ]